# How to pass the output from loop function to setup function?

Tags: arduino, output, parameter-passing

I try to use `Arduino` and make a controller for a robot using fuzzy logic. The input for this code are 2 LDR sensors (labelled by RSensor and LSensor) and the outputs are RMotor and LMotor. I had studied some examples, and my code throws these errors:

```
tryingagain:12: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
tryingagain.ino: In function 'void setup()':
tryingagain:38: error: 'FuzzyInput' was not declared in this scope
tryingagain:38: error: 'RSensor' was not declared in this scope
tryingagain:38: error: expected type-specifier before 'FuzzyInput'
tryingagain:38: error: expected `;' before 'FuzzyInput'
tryingagain:39: error: 'whiteRS' was not declared in this scope
tryingagain:40: error: 'greyRS' was not declared in this scope
tryingagain:41: error: 'blackRS' was not declared in this scope
tryingagain:43: error: 'fuzzy' was not declared in this scope
tryingagain:46: error: 'LSensor' was not declared in this scope
```

these errors are repeated for every each single variable used.
My question is, I have already declared these variables before in the setup function. It cant be called in loop function? If not, how to pass those variable values from one function to another function?

Here is my arduino code:

```
#include <FuzzyRule.h>
#include <FuzzyComposition.h>
#include <Fuzzy.h>
#include <FuzzyRuleConsequent.h>
#include <FuzzyOutput.h>
#include <FuzzyInput.h>
#include <FuzzyIO.h>
#include <FuzzySet.h>
#include <FuzzyRuleAntecedent.h>


Fuzzy* fuzzy = new Fuzzy();

FuzzySet* whiteRS = new FuzzySet(0, 0, 0.1, 0.45);
FuzzySet* greyRS = new FuzzySet(0.15, 0.4, 0.6, 0.85);
FuzzySet* blackRS = new FuzzySet(0.55, 0.9, 1, 1);

FuzzySet* whiteLS = new FuzzySet(0, 0, 0.1, 0.45);
FuzzySet* greyLS = new FuzzySet(0.15, 0.4, 0.6, 0.85);
FuzzySet* blackLS = new FuzzySet(0.55, 0.9, 1, 1);

int LDR0 = 0;                         //analog pin to which LDR is connected, here we          set it to 0 so it means A0
int LDR1 = 1;                         //analog pin to which LDR is connected, here we set it to 1 so it means A1
int LDRValue0 = 0;                    //that’s a variable to store LDR0 values
int LDRValue1 = 0;                    //that’s a variable to store LDR1 values 
int LDRMax=800;
int LDRMin=100;


 void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);     //we mostly use13 because there is already a built in yellow LED in arduino which shows output when 13 pin is enabled
 pinMode(12, OUTPUT);     //we mostly use12 because there is already a built in yellow LED in arduino which shows output when 12 pin is enabled
// FuzzyInput
 FuzzyInput* RSensor = new FuzzyInput(1);
 RSensor->addFuzzySet(whiteRS);
 RSensor->addFuzzySet(greyRS);
 RSensor->addFuzzySet(blackRS);

 fuzzy->addFuzzyInput(RSensor);

 // FuzzyInput
 FuzzyInput* LSensor = new FuzzyInput(2);
 LSensor->addFuzzySet(whiteLS);
 LSensor->addFuzzySet(greyLS);
 LSensor->addFuzzySet(blackLS);

 fuzzy->addFuzzyInput(LSensor);

 // FuzzyOutput
 FuzzyOutput* RMotor= new FuzzyOutput(1);

 FuzzySet* slowRM = new FuzzySet(0, 0, 0.2, 0.8);
 RMotor->addFuzzySet(slowRM);
 FuzzySet* fastRM = new FuzzySet(0.2, 0.8, 1, 1);
 RMotor->addFuzzySet(fastRM);

 fuzzy->addFuzzyOutput(RMotor);

 FuzzyOutput* LMotor= new FuzzyOutput(2);

 FuzzySet* slowLM = new FuzzySet(0, 0, 0.2, 0.8);
 LMotor->addFuzzySet(slowLM);
 FuzzySet* fastLM = new FuzzySet(0.2, 0.8, 1, 1);
 LMotor->addFuzzySet(fastLM);

 fuzzy->addFuzzyOutput(LMotor);

 // Building FuzzyRule1
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSWhiteAndLSBlack = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSWhiteAndLSBlack->joinWithAND(whiteRS, blackLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenRMSlow = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenRMSlow->addOutput(slowRM);

 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule1 = new FuzzyRule(1, ifRSWhiteAndLSBlack, thenRMSlow);
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule1);

 // Building FuzzyRule2
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSGreyAndLSWhite = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSGreyAndLSWhite->joinWithAND(greyRS, whiteLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenLMfast = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenLMfast->addOutput(fastLM);

 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule2 = new FuzzyRule(2, ifRSGreyAndLSWhite, thenLMfast);
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule2);

  // Building FuzzyRule3
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSGreyAndLSGrey = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSGreyAndLSGrey->joinWithAND(greyRS, greyLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenLMslowAndRMslow = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenLMslowAndRMslow->addOutput(slowLM);
 thenLMslowAndRMslow->addOutput(slowRM);


 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule3 = new FuzzyRule(3, ifRSGreyAndLSGrey, thenLMslowAndRMslow);
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule3);

  // Building FuzzyRule4
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSBlackAndLSWhite = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSBlackAndLSWhite->joinWithAND(blackRS, whiteLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenLMslow = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenLMslow->addOutput(slowLM);

 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule4 = new FuzzyRule(4, ifRSBlackAndLSWhite, thenLMslow);
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule4);

  // Building FuzzyRule5
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSBlackAndLSGrey = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSBlackAndLSGrey->joinWithAND(blackRS, greyLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenRMslow = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenRMslow->addOutput(slowRM);

 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule5 = new FuzzyRule(5, ifRSBlackAndLSGrey, thenRMslow);
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule5);

   // Building FuzzyRule6
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSBlackAndLSBlack = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSBlackAndLSBlack->joinWithAND(blackRS, blackLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenLMslowAndRMslow1 = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenLMslowAndRMslow1 ->addOutput(slowLM);
 thenLMslowAndRMslow1 ->addOutput(slowRM);

 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule6 = new FuzzyRule(6, ifRSBlackAndLSBlack, thenLMslowAndRMslow1 );
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule6);

   // Building FuzzyRule7
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSWhiteAndLSGrey = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSWhiteAndLSGrey->joinWithAND(whiteRS, greyLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenRMfast = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenRMfast->addOutput(fastRM);

 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule7 = new FuzzyRule(7, ifRSWhiteAndLSGrey, thenRMfast);
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule7);

  // Building FuzzyRule8
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent* ifRSGreyAndLSBlack = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 ifRSGreyAndLSBlack->joinWithAND(greyRS, blackLS);

 FuzzyRuleConsequent* thenRMslow1 = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 thenRMslow1->addOutput(slowRM);

 FuzzyRule* fuzzyRule8 = new FuzzyRule(8, ifRSGreyAndLSBlack, thenRMslow1);
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule8);

}

void loop()
{
  LDRValue0 = analogRead(LDR0);          //reads the ldr’s value through LDR which we have set to Analog input 0 “A0″
  delay(50);                                                //This is the output value by which LDR sends value to arduino
                                                          //right sensor
  LDRValue1 = analogRead(LDR1);          //reads the ldr’s value through LDR which we have set to Analog input 1 “A1″
  delay(50);                                                //This is the output value by which LDR sends value to arduino
                                                        //leftsensor

  //Finding normalization value for LDRValue0 and LDRValue1
 RSensor=(LDRValue0-LDRMin)/(LDRMax-LDRMin);
 LSensor=(LDRValue1-LDRMin)/(LDRMax-LDRMin);

  fuzzy->setInput(1, RSensor);
  fuzzy->setInput(2, LSensor);


  fuzzy->fuzzify();

  float output1 = fuzzy->defuzzify(1);
  float output2 = fuzzy->defuzzify(2);

  delay(100000);
}
```

Comment: All those errors are inconsequential. The REAL error is the first one. Figure out why Fuzzy* fuzzy = new Fuzzy(); is throwing an error and the rest will be fixed.

Comment: Could you please post Fuzzy.h?